# How to close a section of a sphere flat while retaining closest shape?

Tags: modeling, mesh

I'd like to cap an irregular section of a sphere with a flat surface while not modifying the section shape:

[image]

I'd like to get to s.t. like this:

[image]

but without the errors (non manifold vertex with 3 points of junctions)
Starting from the section above, I normally would select non manifold (the border) with Alt-Ctrl-Shift-M then create face, fill, or grid fill. But all these create non manifold artifacts. 
Or I could use loop tools; but they modify the shape. My question:
How can create s.t like the second image, that is close the surface optimally, without artifacts and respecting starting shape? Just adding to the outside of the shape so as to keep it closest to the original?
Hope I've been clear... is there a way? Scripting is ok, too...

[The blend](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1q7gMdHwfJwgJb9UI-phtggyvMZjBNR_D)

Comment: Why do you think there is non-manifold geometry on the second screenshot? Triangles, even long and tiny, aren't non-manifold geometry, though they aren't preferred most often. The easiest way to make flat face out of irregular shape on the first screenshot is to fill a face from it and triangulate it with Ctrl+T. Probably if you add information about why do you want that sphere segment to have a base face it would allow others to propose a different way.

Comment: Before triangulating, you need to close the hole. That's the problem. Download the blend, try as I described. That screenshot I did with select non manifold (from edge select) and T. The edges near the border are non manifold. Those problems arise from separating a mesh into parts and then having to set them back while keeping track of attachment vertices/zones. That mesh is a part of the head of mace that will be collected one by one by a player... hence the problem

Answer (score 2):

This can be accomplished pretty easily with the knife tool.

[image: using the kife]

I first positioned the object how I wanted it, and then pressed k, clicked on one point outside the mesh, then moved the mouse to the opposed side, and clicked to create a cut like the one above. Then all you need to do is delete all the vertices of the sphere to the right of the cut, and the knife tool will have created a smooth edge for your sphere segment.

One possible issue is that the knife tool only does the half of the sphere facing you. In that case, delete the half of the sphere you can't see, and use a mirror modifier to duplicate the side with the knife cut so it makes a full sphere again.

Final result:

[image: result]